# How to label Figures and Tables in 2 sections with prefix and separately?

Tags: cross-referencing, appendix, springernature, extended-characters

I am writing a manuscript using the latex template of Springer-Nature publisher. However, the journal I am interested has the special requirement that two sections, 'Extended Data' and 'Supplementary information' should be included in the same latex file, and:

The captions of figures in 'Extended Data' should be named as Extended Data Fig. 1, Extended Data Fig. 2, etc. I want to cross-ref these figures, so when I use 'Extended Data Fig.~\ref{The label of Extended Data Fig. 1}', I also want it to be complied as 'Extended Data Fig. 1' with the cross-ref link button.

The captions of figures in 'Supplementary information' should also be named as Supplementary Fig. 1, Supplementary Fig. 2, etc. The captions of tables in in 'Supplementary information' should also be named as Supplementary Table 1, Supplementary Table 2, etc.

Moreover, I want to add some subsections in 'Supplementary information', which are Supplementary Note 1, Supplementary Note 2, etc. I also want to cross-ref these subsections in my maintext, but I don't know how to do that, because if I use '~\ref{The label of Supplementary Note 1}', it will be compiled as the no. of the subsection in the whole file, not 1, 2, etc.

I know it's complicated a bit, but I really appreciate it if someone can let me know how to do this. Thank you so much!

You can find the template file in the link:
https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

Comment: If I were writing the template, I would create new float types for Suplementary figures and tables with their own counters.  \Label will record \thesupfigure (assuming supfigure is the name of the counter used).

Comment: Hi @Luke-ZZ can you point me / share the additional information required by Springer? I can't locate on the link you provided. It isn't in the instructions included in the journal template.

Comment: Hi@alchemist. Thank you for your effort. This template was used in all the journals of Springer-natuer publisher, and some of the journals have special requirements. The journal I am submitting to is Nature Materials, and the requirements of Extended Data and Supplementary Information can be found on this link, or you can find that recent papers published on Nature Mateirals have Extended Data and Supplementary Notes numbered like I said. Thank you so much!
https://www.nature.com/nmat/submission-guidelines/aip-and-formatting#extended-data-figures

Comment: Hi@John Kormylo. I am not very familiar with Latex, could you please let me know how to create new float types like you said? Thank you so much.